# Parsing string for retrieving date in UNIX and freeBSD

Tags: sh, gnu, freebsd

I have a string in following format:
`YYYY-MM-DD`

how can i convert it to date on UNIX **and** freeBSD?
I know it is

`date -d $VAR +'%Y-%m-%d'` on GNU

and

`date -jf $VAR +'%Y-%m-%d'` on freeBSD

But what if my script (in sh, not in bash) have to work on both OS? How can I combine it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because date command is different a kind of solution might be if detect correct platform:

```
#!/bin/sh

VAR='2014-03-15'
platform='uknown'
str="$(uname)"

if [ "$str" == 'Linux' ]; then
    platform='linux'
elif [ "$str" == 'FreeBSD' ]; then
    platform='freebsd'
fi
```

Then according to the platform you can do:

```
if [ "$platform" == 'linux' ]; then
    date -d "$VAR" +'%Y-%m-%d'
elif [ "$platform" == 'freebsd' ]; then
    date -jf "%Y-%m-%d" "$VAR" +'%Y-%m-%d'
fi
```

Also I think you are missing format for the command:

```
date -jf $VAR +'%Y-%m-%d'
```

I think i should be:

```
date -jf "format" $VAR +'%Y-%m-%d'
```